# How to call a PyObject method by a variable name inside of Py.GIL() block?

Tags: c#, python, .net, method-call, python.net

I want to have a function, which allows me to call methods on given `PyObject` by their name with an object array as parameters.
I tried using `InvokeMethod` first, but it only allows `PyObject` arrays (or tuples) as parameters.

I have the following code:

```
public static object PyFunctionCall(PyObject obj, string methodname, object[] parameters)
{
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        return obj[methodname](parameters);
    }
}
```

This however does not work, as it is not a proper functioncall...

What do I have to do?

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/331